# How to use conditional statement in middle of concatenation

Tags: php, concatenation, shortcode

So I have three variables $blue_tooltip_icon, $red_tooltip_icon, and $gray_tooltip_icon. Now I would like a specific variable to be output depending on what attribute is passed onto a WordPress shortcode. So either $blue_tooltip_icon if 'blue' is entered, $red_tooltip_icon if 'red' is entered, and $gray_tooltip_icon if 'gray' is entered.

The problem is how to go about this. I tried using an if statement but found out that that's not possible in concatenation.

This is what I am trying to output via the shortcode with the tooltip icon being variable based on what color is entered through the shortcode attribute.

```
$message = '<span data-title="'.$atts['text'].'" class="tooltip">'.$content .$blue_tooltip_icon.'</span>';
```

Comment: _if 'blue' is entered,_ Ok, so which variable holds the `blue` value here in your code?

Comment: I wonder why you need different icons. If the difference really only is the color, then usually a single icon  in form of a background and a tintin via css in one of those colors is enough.

Comment: I wouldn't use a conditional operator. I'd use an `if` statement before this to set a variable, and then use that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this helps you.

```php
<?php
// Cleaner way

$blue_tooltip_icon = 'blue';
$red_tooltip_icon = 'red';
$green_tooltip_icon = 'green';

$atts['text'] = 'john';
$content = 'content';

$icons = [
    'blue' => $blue_tooltip_icon,
    'red' => $red_tooltip_icon,
    'green' => $green_tooltip_icon
];

$input = 'red';

//$message = '<span data-title="' . $atts['text'] . '" class="tooltip">' . $content . $icons[$input] . '</span>';

// Awkward style with ternary operator

$input = 'green';

$message = '<span data-title="' . $atts['text'] . '" class="tooltip">' . $content . (($input == "red") ? $red_tooltip_icon : (($input == "blue") ? $blue_tooltip_icon : $green_tooltip_icon)) . '</span>';

echo $message;
```

Comment: hey man this worked but now i am getting an error saying undefined array key

Comment: hi, it means you are accessing an array with a key that does not exist. Please, share a code that you wrote.